# django - queryset diference - not working as i expect

Tags: django, django-queryset

Another newbie problem i am afraid. I have this form with 3 lists. The goal being to change the queryset for 2 of the lists (see code in view)

**form.py**

```
class AddGameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    won_lag = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('1','Home') , ('2', 'Away') ], )
    home_team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all(),required=True )
    away_team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all(), required=True )

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ()
```

**view.py**

```
def game_add(request, match_id):
    # used to create a new Game

    """ return http response page for creating a new Game """

    # Adding a new Game so just make a new one
    game = Game()

    # Get the match specified in the Querystring because we will need it to figure out     who the home team
    # and away team are.
    try:
        match = Match.objects.get(id=match_id)
    except Match.DoesNotExist:
        # we have no object!  do something
        #todo: redirect to list match page?
    pass

    # get form
    form = AddGameForm(request.POST or None, instance=game)

    # Change the Queryset for Home and Away team to show only players that are on the team
    #  AND have not already played in a game so we need to get the "DIFFERENCE" between all
    #  team members and any players that have already played in the match
    home_players = Player.objects.filter(team=match.home_team)            # All Home Team members
    away_players = Player.objects.filter(team=match.away_team)            # All Away Team members
    already_played_in_match_players = Game.objects.filter(match=match)    # This is both home and away players
                                                                      # that have played in a Game on this match

    form.fields['home_team'].queryset = home_players.exclude(pk__in=already_played_in_match_players)
    form.fields['away_team'].queryset = away_players.exclude(pk__in=already_played_in_match_players)
...
```

In my DB i have the following:

```
Team 1
   Player 1
   Player 2
Team 2
   Player 3

Match 1
   no games
```

So when i open the form, as expected, the home_team list shows both Player1, Player2 and the away_team list shows Player3

So I choose Player 1 and Player3, and save the game.
Now the DB has the following data

```
Team 1
   Player 1
   Player 2
Team 2
   Player 3

Match 1
   Game 1 between Player1 and Player3
```

I decide to add another Game so i open the GameAddForm and expect to have the home_team list show only Player2 and the away_team list to show no players.

However, in reality, what happens is that the home_team list acts as expected, **but** the away_team list still shows Player 3.

I am totally confused as to why it works correctly for the home team but not the away team.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, figured it out. Essentially the problem was with the following line:

```
already_played_in_match_players = Game.objects.filter(match=match)
```

which returns a queryset of **Games**, not **Players**.

Since I wanted to get **Players**, I had to start with Player.object. Which meant that I had to query through the Game → Player1 and Game → Player2  relations backwards. Here's what the docs say about it:

```
Lookups that span relationships

To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want

...

To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.
```

I broke it into several steps for clarity.

```
inner_query = Game.objects.filter(match=match)  # Gets all games in this match
```

Then i used the following:

```
Player.objects.filter(player1__in=inner_query)
```

which essentially says, Get all the Player objects that are referenced by the player1 foreignkey in any Game object in the innerquery queryset.

Next I used the | (pipe) to UNION a queryset for player1 and player2
so it resulted in this line:

```
already_played_players = Player.objects.filter(player1__in=inner_query) | Player.objects.filter(player2__in=inner_query)
```

This had the desired affect of giving me a list of all players who had already played in the match.

**Summary of change**

I changed the offending line to the following:

```
...

inner_query = Game.objects.filter(match=match)    # All games in this match

# Now use reverse relation to get the Player1 union Player2 to get all players who have played in this match so far
already_played_players = Player.objects.filter(player1__in=inner_query) | Player.objects.filter(player2__in=inner_query)

...
```